# ¿Cómo insertar un <img> (con src) en el DOM a través de una función en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, insert, img

me podrían indicar cómo realizar esto de forma genérica?

lo que necesito es crear una etiqueta dentro de un DIV ya existente, y que esa etiqueta ya se inserte con la dirección de la imagen. Todo en una función.

Estoy tratado de crear una app web en la que se pueda trasmitir radio en vivo. Entonces tengo un reproductor genérico en el cual quiero se pueda controlar la emisión (volumen, play, pause, etc.) y además se pueda visualizar la imagen de la emisora (Radio) que se esté trasmitiendo en el momento. Aparte del reproductor tengo "items" en los cuales muestro las diferentes emisoras para que el usuario pueda elegir. Para ello necesito que en cada ítem donde se muestran las emisoras (Radios) exista un evento click que me permita, además de pausar la emisora que esté sonando, cambiar la imagen del reproductor actualizándolo a lo que se esté ejecutando en ese momento.

Dejo parte del código, espero haber sido claro:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="radio.css">
    <title>radio</title>
  </head>

  <body>
```

//////CONTENEDOR DE RADIOS//////

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="items_radios">

//////RADIOS///////

        <div class="item" id="del_plata"> Del Plata
          <audio id="audio">
            <source src="http://radios-mp3-uy.cdn.nedmedia.io/uy-delplata.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
          </audio> 
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="babel" > Babel
          <audio id="audio1">
            <source src="https://radios.iwstreaming.uy/8030/stream" type="audio/mpeg" />
          </audio>
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="del_sol" > Del Sol
          <audio id="audio2">
            <source src="https://radio1.dl.uy:9952/?type=http&nocache=2780&dbl=0" type="audio/mpeg" />
          </audio>
        </div>
```

////REPRODUCTOR////

```
          <div class="player">
        <div class="player__controls">

//////DIV DE IMAGEN//////

        <div class="player__album">
          <img id="img_gral" src="./img/del_plata.png" alt="Album Cover" class="player__img" loading="lazy" />
        </div>
```

//////BOTONES//////

```
          <div id="btn_gral" class="player__btn player__btn--medium blue play">
            <i id="btn" class="bi-play" aria-hidden="true" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 2em;"></i>
          </div>
   
        </div>
</div>
```

```
    <script>

    const audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    const playPause = document.getElementById("play");
    
      const div = document.getElementsByClassName("player__album"),
      imagen = document.createElement('img');
    
      function agregarImagen(){
    
      imagen.src = "./img/babel.jpg";
      imagen.width = 400;
      
      div.appendChild(imagen);
    
    }
    
    
    ///EVENTO CLICK///
    playPause1.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        play_rmv();
        babel_img();
        agregarImagen();
      } else {
        audio.pause();
        play_rmv();
      }
    });

</script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a  a [es.so]. Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: ten en cuenta que esta no es una plataforma del tipo _denme el código de esto_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías probar algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="agregarImg()">Agregar Imagen</button>
    <div id="imgContainer"></div>

    <script>
      function agregarImg() {
        const imagen = "imagen.png" //Img en variable para enviar lo que desees
        const contenedor = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
        contenedor.insertAdjacentHTML(
          "beforeend",
          `<img src=${imagen} alt=${imagen}>` // Backticks para img variable
        );
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notarás que la imagen la deposité en una variable, para que puedas enviarla en forma dinámica, luego al hacer el insertAdjacentHTML la etiqueta img la puse entre backticks para poder poner los valores variables adentro entre ${}. Si pones en la misma carpeta, cualquier imagen llamada imagen.png puedes incluso probarlo en funcionamiento.

Otra forma de hacerlo es haciendo en cada llamado a la función un create de un div y luego un appendChild.

Espero te sirva, quedo a las órdenes.

En respuesta a tu último comentario, intentaré explicarte lo que sucede.

Esto sería el HTML, en el solo puse un boton que llama a la funcion agregarImg y un div con id=imgContainer que es el contenedor donde se agregarán las imágenes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="agregarImg()">Agregar Imagen</button>
    <div id="imgContainer"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Por otro lado tenemos el script, en el que iré comentando línea por línea.
Inicio Script

```
<script>
```

Declaro la función q llamaré desde el button

```
function agregarImg() {
```

Deposito el nombre de imagen en variable, para poder utilizar el código si este nombre lo traes de una lista o base de datos por ejemplo, en ese caso podrías usar un bucle, y por cada nombre de imagen en la lista, agregar una imagen al div.

```
const imagen = "imagen.png";
```

Defino donde voy a agregar imagenes, capturo el div con id: imgContainer

```
const contenedor = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
```

Ahora le digo que a ese contenedor, le agregue antes de terminar, una etiqueta  donde el atributo src recibe como valor el nombre de la imagen depositado en la variable imagen. (Esto se encarga de agregar una nueva etiqueta img dentro del div imgContainer, cada vez que se invoca la función agregarImg, es decir, cada vez que se presiona el botón.

```
contenedor.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`<img src=${imagen} alt=${imagen}>`);
```

Cierro función agregarImg

```
}
```

Cierro Script

```
</script>
```

---

En tu código hice lo siguiente, el Script quedó así:

```
  <script>
    let selectedAudioId = "";
    let audio = "";
    const playPause = document.getElementById("playBtn");
    const div = document.getElementById("player__album");

      <script>
        let selectedAudioId = "";
        let audio = "";
        const playPause = document.getElementById("playBtn");
        const div = document.getElementById("player__album");
    
        function setRadio() {
          selectedAudioId = event.target.children[0].id;
          if (audio && selectedAudioId !== audio) {
            audio.pause();
          }
          audio = document.getElementById(event.target.children[0].id);
          audio.play();
          agregarImagen();
        }
    
        imagen = document.createElement("img");
    
        function agregarImagen() {
          /* imagen.src = "./img/babel.jpg"; */
          imagen.src = selectedAudioId + ".jpg";
          imagen.width = 400;
    
          div.appendChild(imagen);
        }
    
        playPause.addEventListener("click", () => {
          if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            play_rmv();
            babel_img();
          } else {
            audio.pause();
            play_rmv();
          }
        });
      </script>
```

Este hace que se reproduzca la radio al presionar sobre el nombre en la lista y agrega la imagen, para esto puse en la misma carpeta 2 archivos jpg, uno llamado video.jpg (este es el logo de delplata) y otro llamado video1.jpg (este es el logo de babel), al presionar encima identifica sobre que audio se presinó y hace el play de ese audio. Antes de eso verifica si hay algo reproduciendo y lo pausa antes de cambiar.

finalmente dejo las funciones para el boton play, agregé en el HTML un span en el play porque no me aparecía el botón y no quería instalar cosas de otros orígenes. Al dar sobre play se pause y reproduce la emisora actual.

Y para cambiar de emisora solo debes presionar sobre el nombre de la que desees.

Solo lo dejé funcionando para del plata y babel para que tengas ejemplo.

Te pasó el código completo ahora del html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="radio.css" />
    <title>radio</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="items_radios">
        //////RADIOS///////

        <div class="item" id="del_plata" onclick="setRadio(this)">
          Del Plata
          <audio id="audio">
            <source
              src="http://radios-mp3-uy.cdn.nedmedia.io/uy-delplata.mp3"
              type="audio/mpeg"
            />
          </audio>
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="babel" onclick="setRadio(this)">
          Babel
          <audio id="audio1">
            <source
              src="https://radios.iwstreaming.uy/8030/stream"
              type="audio/mpeg"
            />
          </audio>
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="del_sol">
          Del Sol
          <audio id="audio2">
            <source
              src="https://radio1.dl.uy:9952/?type=http&nocache=2780&dbl=0"
              type="audio/mpeg"
            />
          </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
          <div class="player__controls">
            <div id="player__album"></div>
            <div
              id="btn_gral"
              class="player__btn player__btn--medium blue play"
            >
              <span id="playBtn"
                ><i
                  id="btn"
                  class="bi-play"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 2em"
                ></i
                >Play</span
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Se puede mejorar bastante pero algo corto de tiempos, quería que tengas un ejemplo funcional para poder avanzar.

Comment: Excelente alternativa Luis! muchas gracias! aunque sigo sin entender qué sucede..

Comment: Agregué una explicación línea por línea en la respuesta, espero te ayude a entender mejor. Quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, tu comentario fue clarísimo. Ahí edité la pregunta y agregué parte del código ya que sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Acabo de ver que editaste la respuesta, disculpas soy nuevo en este sitio y en programación. No estoy entendiendo bien todos los métodos que usaste y no pude adaptar el código. Y entiendo que mi pregunta ya deja de ser específica. Voy a leer un poco sobre los métodos y haré preguntas más concretas, gracias nuevamente por tu tiempo! saludos!

Comment: Todo es práctica, quedo a las órdenes!

Answer (score 0):

Esto creo que es lo que buscas, hice lo más sencillo posible el código, puedes ejecutarlo para ver lo que hace.

**EJEMPLO:**

```js
const div = document.getElementById("div"),
imagen = document.createElement("img");

function agregarImagen(){

  imagen.src = "https://i.blogs.es/594843/chrome/450_1000.jpg";
  imagen.width = 400;
  
  div.appendChild(imagen);

}

agregarImagen();
```

```html
<div id="div">

</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Tu respuesta es excelente!! aún así no logro lo que quiero. Debo tener otro error por ahí... Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: dime que es lo que necesitas en el código y te ayudo.

Comment: @IgnacioGrilli deberías incluir que has intentado hasta el momento, que tienes y cuál es el resultado esperado. De esta manera Daniel y otros van a poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Logré resolverlo en la función anterior, cuando quitaba la imagen. Cambié el ".remove()" por ".src = selectedAudioId" que es la variable que contiene la imagen:

```
let img_gral=document.getElementById("img_gral");
function babel_img() {
  img_gral.remove();
}
```

Pasó a ser:

```
let img_gral=document.getElementById("img_gral");
function babel_img() {
  img_gral.src = selectedAudioId;
}
```

Básicamente en vez de quitar y luego colocar, pasó a sustituir. Agradezco nuevamente los comentarios ya que sin ellos no hubiera podido.